# AWS EC2 instance: Error while connecting to a private instance from a bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bastion-host

In AWS, I have created a Bastion host (10.0.10.182) using Amazon Linux 2 and from there I am able to connect to a EC2 private subnet instance (10.0.20.121) (amazon linux 2). (However, this works fine only for the first time.)

After connecting to the Private instance, in order to pull a git repo from github on the private instance, I run the ssh-keygen on the private instance and copy that to github Keys. I can see the .ssh dir in the home dir with the usual files - known_hosts, authorized_keys, id_rsa, id_rsa.pub.

When the original connection from bastion host to private ec2instance times out, I am unable to re-login to the private instance via the bastion host. I get the following message:
ssh -i TestVPC_NCal.pem ec2-user@10.0.20.121
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Here is the ssh debug log generated on the Bastion host:

> ######Begin ssh debug log ######### [ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-182 ~]$ ssh -v -i TestVPC_NCal.pem ec2-user@10.0.20.121 OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying
> options for * debug1: Connecting to 10.0.20.121 [10.0.20.121] port 22.
> debug1: Connection established. debug1: key_load_public: No such file
> or directory debug1: identity file TestVPC_NCal.pem type -1 debug1:
> key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file
> TestVPC_NCal.pem-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for
> protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 debug1:
> Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 debug1:
> Authenticating to 10.0.20.121:22 as 'ec2-user' debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug1: kex:
> algorithm: curve25519-sha256 debug1: kex: host key algorithm:
> ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 debug1: kex: server->client cipher:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
> debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:
>  compression: none debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64
> dh_need=64 debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 debug1:
> expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY debug1: Server host key:
> ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:5W++Ewk+lx2YXUUY1xhhttjKG3KVWvIOTvtp7THBFJc
> debug1: Host '10.0.20.121' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
> debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:2 debug1: rekey
> after 134217728 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting
> SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1: rekey after
> 134217728 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received debug1:
> kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug1: Authentications that
> can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic debug1: Next
> authentication method: gssapi-keyex debug1: No valid Key exchange
> context debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic debug1:
> Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No
> Kerberos credentials available (default cache:
> KEYRING:persistent:1000)
>
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
> information No Kerberos credentials available (default cache:
> KEYRING:persistent:1000)
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Trying private
> key: TestVPC_NCal.pem debug1: Authentications that can continue:
> publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic debug1: No more authentication
> methods to try. Permission denied
> (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). [ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-182 ~]$
>
> ########### End debug log ########

I wonder if the running the ssh-keygen on EC2 private instance is somehow causing the error. Any pointers to resolve this are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by creating the TestVPC_NCal.pem file (associated with the EC2 private instance) on the EC2 private instance while the connection was working. The clue was in the log I posted in my question:
##############
Connecting to 10.0.20.121 [10.0.20.121] port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file TestVPC_NCal.pem type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file TestVPC_NCal.pem-cert type -1 debug1:
##############

When the connection timed-out overnight, I was able to log back in to EC2 private instance with no issues.

Comment: You can use code blocks or quotes to format the output better, making it easier to read.